# My QR reader without Google ZXing installed

Tags: android, zxing

Basing on [this tutorial](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/android-barcode-and-qr-scanner-example/), I made an app for reading QR codes. However, this app requires com.google.zxing.client.android installed. Is there any way to add this package to my app so that I won't have to install Google reader? I found com.google.zxing package at Maven but id didn't contain necessary components.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29514124/2960788

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few library projects that use ZXing library and provide ability to use QR code within your application.

You can try one of these:

https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner

https://github.com/dlazaro66/QRCodeReaderView

Comment: Thanks a lot. The second link was helpful for me. At first I got stuck cause I didn't know how to attach this project to my one but eventually it started working.