# ZXing barcode scanner in custom layout in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, zxing, barcode-scanner

I develope ZXing barcode continuous scanner following [this page](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded) on Android Studio.

My App `build.gradle` had include:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()

    maven {
        url "https://raw.github.com/embarkmobile/zxing-android-minimal/mvn-repo/maven-repository/"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile files('src/main/jniLibs/scanditsdk-android-4.7.5.jar')
    compile files('src/main/jniLibs/httpclient-4.0.jar')

    compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.0.3@aar'
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0'
}
```

And my `Fragment.xml`'s layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#00CC00"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="100">

    <com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CompoundBarcodeView
        android:id="@+id/barcode_scanner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="40"
        >

    </com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CompoundBarcodeView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle"
        >


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnStartScan"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="25"
            android:text="Start"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonstyle"
            style="@style/button_style"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnStopScan"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="25"
            android:text="Stop"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonstyle"
            style="@style/button_style"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnPauseScan"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="25"
            android:text="Pause"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonstyle"
            style="@style/button_style"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnResumeScan"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="25"
            android:text="Resume"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonstyle"
            style="@style/button_style"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Then, my Fragment code look like following:

```
public class CMCSMOFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    private CompoundBarcodeView barcodeView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (container == null) {
            return null;
        }

        View v;
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cmcsmo_layout, container, false);

        barcodeView = (CompoundBarcodeView) v.findViewById(R.id.barcode_scanner);
        barcodeView.decodeContinuous(callback);

        return v;
    }

    private BarcodeCallback callback = new BarcodeCallback() {
        @Override
        public void barcodeResult(BarcodeResult result) {
            if (result.getText() != null) {
                barcodeView.setStatusText(result.getText());
            }

            //Do something with code result
        }

        @Override
        public void possibleResultPoints(List<ResultPoint> resultPoints) {
        }
    };
}
```

And when I build my app, the `CompoundBarcodeView` only show a **black view** with ZXing text:

> Place a barcode inside the viewfinder rectangle to scan it.

**Edit:**

Follow **Lennon** suggestion, I had used `zxing-minimum` but it doesn't allow to work on Portrait mode :(.

How should I do to solve this problem? Thanks for all help!

Comment: why do you implement view.onClicklistener with no onclick function?

Comment: My class is too long, so I just post code for my problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's so easy, owner of ZXing said that only add following code into `onResume` and `onPause` overrided method:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    barcodeView.resume();
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    barcodeView.pause();
    super.onPause();
}
```

Comment: I copied all your code but I am still only getting a black screen

Comment: Please follow `https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded` for more detail.

Answer (score 3):

You must initialize the barcodeView.

Try this code:

```
IntentIntegrator integrator = IntentIntegrator.forSupportFragment(this);
barcodeView.initializeFromIntent(integrator.createScanIntent());
```

https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the minimal library of zxing like following link: https://github.com/andreipro/zxing-android-minimal

It's easy. You just have to add these lines into your `gradle`

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()

    maven {
        url "https://raw.github.com/embarkmobile/zxing-android-minimal/mvn-repo/maven-repository/"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:22.2.0'

    // Zxing minimal libraries
    compile 'com.embarkmobile:zxing-android-minimal:2.0.0@aar'
    compile 'com.embarkmobile:zxing-android-integration:2.0.0@aar'
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.0.1'
}
```

And then just call the barcode using this

```
new IntentIntegrator(this).initiateScan(); // `this` is the current Activity
```

In you case, you wanna use a custom layout, so you must create your custom layout following some parameters, such as the layout below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <SurfaceView android:id="@+id/zxing_preview_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

    <com.google.zxing.client.android.ViewfinderView
        android:id="@+id/zxing_viewfinder_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/zxing_result_view"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/zxing_result_view"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:baselineAligned="false">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="@dimen/zxing_standard_padding">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="right|center_vertical">

                <ImageView android:id="@+id/zxing_barcode_image_view"
                    android:layout_width="160dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:maxWidth="160dip"
                    android:maxHeight="160dip"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/zxing_half_padding"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/zxing_msg_default_format"
                        android:textColor="@color/zxing_result_minor_text"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:paddingRight="@dimen/zxing_half_padding"/>

                    <TextView android:id="@+id/zxing_format_text_view"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@color/zxing_result_minor_text"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/zxing_msg_default_type"
                        android:textColor="@color/zxing_result_minor_text"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:paddingRight="@dimen/zxing_half_padding"/>

                    <TextView android:id="@+id/zxing_type_text_view"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@color/zxing_result_minor_text"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/zxing_msg_default_time"
                        android:textColor="@color/zxing_result_minor_text"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:paddingRight="@dimen/zxing_half_padding"/>

                    <TextView android:id="@+id/zxing_time_text_view"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@color/zxing_result_minor_text"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView android:id="@+id/zxing_meta_text_view_label"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/zxing_msg_default_meta"
                        android:textColor="@color/zxing_result_minor_text"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:paddingRight="@dimen/zxing_half_padding"/>

                    <TextView android:id="@+id/zxing_meta_text_view"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@color/zxing_result_minor_text"/>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView android:id="@+id/zxing_contents_text_view"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@color/zxing_result_text"
                        android:textColorLink="@color/zxing_result_text"
                        android:textSize="22sp"
                        android:paddingLeft="12dip"
                        android:autoLink="web"
                        android:textIsSelectable="true"/>

                    <TextView android:id="@+id/zxing_contents_supplement_text_view"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@color/zxing_result_text"
                        android:textColorLink="@color/zxing_result_text"
                        android:paddingLeft="12dip"
                        android:autoLink="web"
                        android:textIsSelectable="true"/>

                </LinearLayout>

            </ScrollView>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/zxing_result_button_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center">

            <Button style="@style/zxing_ResultButton"
                android:visibility="gone"/>

            <Button style="@style/zxing_ResultButton"
                android:visibility="gone"/>

            <Button style="@style/zxing_ResultButton"
                android:visibility="gone"/>

            <Button style="@style/zxing_ResultButton"
                android:visibility="gone"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/zxing_status_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:background="@color/zxing_transparent"
            android:text="@string/zxing_msg_default_status"
            android:textColor="@color/zxing_status_text"/>

        <Button android:id="@id/zxing_back_button"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:height="60dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/zxing_button_cancel"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</merge>
```

After that, you can set the above layout into `integrator` like

```
IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
integrator.setCaptureLayout(R.layout.custom_layout);
integrator.initiateScan();
```

But remember, you have to follow those parameters. It means that you have to use the same name for all the views.

Comment: I have done this. Thank you very much. But could I use ZXing minimal on Portrait screen?

Comment: No. Unfortunately I've tried to use it on Portrait, but no success.

Answer (score 0):

Does your app have permission to use the device camera?
Add that permission in your manifest, and then after installing the app, go to your phone settings > apps > your app > permissions.
And then grant the camera permission

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue I just removed

```
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:largeHeap="true"
```

from the manifest and it worked!