# ZXing barcode scanner in custom layout in fragment 2

Tags: android, zxing, barcode-scanner

[Using ZXing Android Embedded](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded)

[Example taken from here and there is the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32627145/zxing-barcode-scanner-in-custom-layout-in-fragment)

My fragment class:

```
    public class ExciseBarcodeScanFragment extends AbstractFragment {
    private Button button;
    private CompoundBarcodeView barcodeView;

    @Override
    public int getTitleRes() {
        return R.string.validation_of_excise_stamps_on_alcohol_products;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_excise_barcode_scan, container, false);
        init(rootView);

        return rootView;
    }

    private void init(View rootView) {
        // ...

        barcodeView = (CompoundBarcodeView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.barcode_scanner);
        barcodeView.decodeContinuous(callback);
    }

    private BarcodeCallback callback = new BarcodeCallback() {
        @Override
        public void barcodeResult(BarcodeResult result) {
            if (result.getText() != null) {
                barcodeView.setStatusText(result.getText());
            }

            //Do something with code result
        }

        @Override
        public void possibleResultPoints(List<ResultPoint> resultPoints) {
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        barcodeView.resume();
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        barcodeView.pause();
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

Fragment xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp">

    <com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CompoundBarcodeView
        android:id="@+id/barcode_scanner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="40"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/manuallyButton"
            style="@style/SearchField.Button"
            android:text="@string/search"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

[Screen](http://screencast.com/t/Q1beXjzR)

I know that comes as a duplicate, but it does not work.
I'm new, I'm sorry if the horrible formatting.
Please help.

Comment: Make sure the app has permission to use the camera

Answer (score 0):

Everything is working. It turns on the emulator as shown does not seem to work, and work on your phone.