# Barcode/QR-Code Scanner customized design

Tags: android, android-layout, barcode-scanner

I want to scan Barcode/QR-Code in my app.

I used Zxing library to achieve this,

```
implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.6.0'
```

I have no issue on scanning and getting value.

But I don't want the separate page for scanning.
I want the scanning part within the layout itself like in an image

[image]

Is it possible to achieve this using Surface-view like we use it for in built app camera.

Please help me to achieve this. Thanks

Comment: I think this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32627145/zxing-barcode-scanner-in-custom-layout-in-fragment) will help you

Comment: I'll try this..

Answer (score 2):

Hi I have a sample project that I have created for scan barcode/QR codes.

I used `com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.2` for my Scanning project. And I have used `Surface-view` to place the camera.

[Use this link](https://github.com/anupa91/BarcodeScanning)

Thanks.!

Comment: I have two screens, if scan is successful on first Screen then the Second Activity will open, here how to initiate SurfaceView? It looks black screen!

Comment: Hi, In the above project I have initiated a `SurfaceView`. Please refer to above project > MainActivity > line number 134 & 144. If you need more help please ask me.
"It looks black screen" - is it from the above shared project or is it from your implementation?