# Use ZXing library on an Android Project

Tags: java, android, qr-code, zxing

I'm trying to build a project with the ZXing library. I used the instructions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708705/how-to-use-zxing-in-android/33536249#33536249) to integrate the library into my Android project and I believe I have done that successfully. However, when I try to build the entire project, there is an error in the Gradle build that refers to a dependency or something similar. However, I think I've already solved all the issues with dependencies.

The returned error in Gradle :
    `org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:prepareDebugDependencies'.`

The message is

> Dependency QRR:android:unspecified on project app resolves to an APK archive which is not supported as a compilation dependency.

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wifmc21fi27htzr/log.txt?dl=0) is the full Gradle log using Stacktrace.

EDIT:

In this project, I used the full ZXing library, not the Embedded or the Minimal.

After the download of the full repo of ZXing [here](https://github.com/zxing/zxing), I've added the `android` folder as a new Module of the project. I've added the dependency on the Gradle file. Then, I've dowloaded the core on the Maven repo, then I imported it as JAR Library. I've added the dependency in the android:build-gradle.

The app:build.gradle is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.mehdi.qrr"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile project(':android')
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}
```

The Project:build-gradle is:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}

repositories {
mavenCentral()

maven {
    url "http://dl.bintray.com/journeyapps/maven"
}
}
```

The android:build-gradle (Gradle file of the ZXing project):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
signingConfigs {
}
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.google.zxing.client.android"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
}
```

Comment: There's not enough information here to help you. We need the full Gradle log. You may also refer to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36698816/gradle-what-is-a-non-zero-exit-value-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: You could also use a Gradle dependency instead  https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded

Comment: Thank you for the answer @cricket_007. What do you mean by "using a Gradle dependency" ?

Comment: The purpose of Gradle is both a build tool and dependency management. When you require a library in your code, you "depend" on it. Click the github link, it tells you what to put in the Gradle file

Comment: I'm using the default ZXing library, so i've tried to add the required dependencies but i still have the same error

`dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile project(':android')
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
}`

Comment: Please edit your question to include that and the actual  text of the stacktrace. You may use the `{}` button to format it if you select the entire text first

Comment: I've successfully used that other library I linked you to, but this question is somewhat a duplicate.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29513940/how-to-import-zxing-to-android-studio

Comment: I've tried to use the ZXing Android Embedded library. I followed the steps to add the different dependencies. But I still have an error when I try to build the entire project, which is:

`Error:(3, 0) Plugin with id 'com.jfrog.bintray' not found.
`

Comment: Did you follow the steps on Github? Those are more accurate than an old StackOverflow post

Comment: Though, I am not sure how you managed to reference that as a plugin. Again, if you showed your Gradle files, then that would be useful if you want a definitive answer to the problem

Comment: Ok, I have done this, after creating a new project:

* Add "zxing-android-embedded" as a New Module, then I add this `compile project(':zxing-android-embedded')` on the app:build.gradle as a dependency.

* Then I followed the steps on Github. They don't specify in which Gradle file we have to add the lines, so I add them to the app Gradle file.

I'm actually now on Android Studio, so I'm sure i forgot to do something.

Comment: You shouldn't compile the project... You only need to add the dependencies section to your app build.gradle file (because the other one says specifically not to add dependencies there).

Comment: That's what i did. Why should I not compile ? I tried to build with `./gradlew assemble`, but still the same error

Comment: I'll tell you once more to please [edit] your question to include all these steps you've taken to get to this error, the text of your Gradle file, as well as the text of the error message

Comment: I added more details of the initial project in the Question post.

Comment: You don't need the `repositories { mavenCentral()...}` section. That isn't the correct location of the code anymore

Comment: Here is the project that I was able to get working (not my personal code, but I made it Gradle compatible).  I think the Readme is in Chinese, but the code is the important thing.  https://github.com/xuxingliu922/DeviceSDK/blob/master/SmartDeviceSDK/build.gradle

Comment: Ok, my bad, I was on the wrong project.

Comment: Actually, it would appear the changes I made to that project have been modified, so no guarantees it works anymore. I was really just trying to point out how to use the Gradle dependencies section to include Zxing

Comment: Actually, the only difference between my project and yours is this line `compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'`. How can i replace it on my Gradle file ?

Comment: Like I said, not "mine", I just made that code work for someone else here on StackOverflow. And it seems you need to include that line, not replace anything. I still think you shouldn't be compiling that additional project. And just make sure your repositories are all correct. You should only need jCenter.

Comment: If I remeove the   ` compile dependency ` from the Gradle file, there'is a error in the initial project

Comment: There are so many errors you could be getting. I don't know what you are seeing by saying "there's an error". I'm am sure, though, that you are probably seeing a different message than the one in your initial post

Comment: You were right, I deleted the `  compile project ('android') ` from the Gradle and it seems to build normally. But now, I have an internal error which refers to a class not found `  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mehdi.qrr/com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.mehdi.qrr-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]] `

Comment: Did you compile both the embedded and Google Zxing libraries like that link to the project?

Comment: Do I need to compile the embedded library ? I'm not using the Embedded in my first project

Comment: Honestly, not sure. All I know is that I was able to run that code without error at one point

Comment: I think i've found the problem. I'm supposed to add the ZXing project as a library. But, it seems like the project is not recognized. How can I add the ZXing project as a library, not as a compilable project ?

Comment: And how did you arrive at that? Like I said, you shouldn't need `compile project()` anywhere in your Gradle. You need `compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'` instead

Comment: I'm not compiling project anymore, like you've told me. I'm just compiling `compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'`. But the error mentionned a class which is in the project, not the library

Comment: Now, I'm pretty sure that the problem is the link between my application, and the Barcode Reader application. If i have the reader app already installed, my app works without any problem. But if the reader app isn't installed, my app crashes. I also found an error in my Manifest's app:
`<activity android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"`. The class CaptureActivity seems not to be recongnized because it's in red